# Remove class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Morning,

Is there a wildcard i can use in jQuery which would remove a class from an element?

I am applying new classes to my info message box, if a users click it once, then clicks it again it is adding the new class, but retains the existing class.

I need to remove the previous class, then add the new class for styling. Any ideas?

```
 <div id="infoMsg" style="display: block; " class="er-green er-red">All submitted feeds are complete.</div>
```

As you can see the original class was er-green, it has then added er-red.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yip:

```
$(this).removeClass('er-green');
$(this).addClass('er-red');
```

Or remove them all first:

> If a class name is included as a parameter, then only that class will be removed from the set of matched elements. If no class names are specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed.

```
$(this).removeClass();
$(this).addClass('er-red');
```

Answer (score 6):

[removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) method

```
$('#infoMsg').removeClass('er-green');//just removes class

$('div').click(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('er-green');//removes class clicked element
   $(this).addClass('er-red');//adds class clicked element
});
```

Comment: moto, can it moto become something that it makes somo

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#infoMsg").removeClass('er-green').addClass('newclass')
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use jquery `removeclass`

```
$('#infoMsg').removeClass('er-green');
```

Like wise you can also add a css class to your html

```
$('#infoMsg').addClass('er-red');
```